# Next.js getServerSideProps returns empty query object when I pressed go back button

Tags: javascript, next.js, browser, server-side-rendering, getserversideprops

On the first page, I do `router.replace()` with new a query. so the URL becomes similar to `someUrl?timestamp=1000`.
After this I move to second page with `router.push()` and press back button on the browser, which takes me back to `someUrl?timestamp=1000`.

Now in `getServerSideProps`, I get empty `query` object. but if I refresh this page, I get the correct `query` object. My goal is to get `query.timestamp` (1000).

What's wrong with going back feature? The result is same with `router.back()`.

```js
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps<PrimaryPageProps> = async (
  context: GetServerSidePropsContext,
) => {
  console.log(context.query); // it returns {}
  const { timestamp } = context.query;
  return {
    props: {
      timestamp: timestamp === undefined ? null : Number(timestamp),
    },
  };
};
```

This is how I updated the query on the first page.

```js
        <Btn
          onClick={() =>
            router.replace(router.pathname, {
              query: { timestamp: Date.now() },
            })
          }
        >
          Update query
        </Btn>
```